# Segmentation Fault running Gearman PHP from the Command Line

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I'm using Ubuntu Natty with PHP 5.3.5 and [PECL Gearman 0.8.0](http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman). Here's the version info:

```
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 13 2011 22:20:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.10, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to run a Gearman Client via the command line (I already have my worker running).

Here's what I get on the command line:

```
root@Local:~/sandbox# php php_gearman_client.php
Sending job
Segmentation fault
```

Here is my worker code:

```
<?php

echo "Starting\n";

# Create our worker object.
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();

# Add default server (localhost).
$gmworker->addServer();

# Register function "reverse" with the server. Change the worker function to
# "reverse_fn_fast" for a faster worker with no output.
$gmworker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");

print "Waiting for job...\n";
while($gmworker->work())
{
  if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  }
}

function reverse_fn($job)
{
  echo "Received job: " . $job->handle() . "\n";

  $workload = $job->workload();
  $workload_size = $job->workloadSize();

  echo "Workload: $workload ($workload_size)\n";

  # This status loop is not needed, just showing how it works
  for ($x= 0; $x < $workload_size; $x++)
  {
    echo "Sending status: " . ($x + 1) . "/$workload_size complete\n";
    $job->sendStatus($x, $workload_size);
    sleep(1);
  }

  $result= strrev($workload);
  echo "Result: $result\n";

  # Return what we want to send back to the client.
  return $result;
}

# A much simpler and less verbose version of the above function would be:
function reverse_fn_fast($job)
{
  return strrev($job->workload());
}

?>
```

And here is my client code:

```
<?php

# Create our client object.
$gmclient= new GearmanClient();

# Add default server (localhost).
$gmclient->addServer();

echo "Sending job\n";

# Send reverse job
do
{
  $result = $gmclient->do("reverse", "Hello!");

  # Check for various return packets and errors.
  switch($gmclient->returnCode())
  {
    case GEARMAN_WORK_DATA:
      echo "Data: $result\n";
      break;
    case GEARMAN_WORK_STATUS:
      list($numerator, $denominator)= $gmclient->doStatus();
      echo "Status: $numerator/$denominator complete\n";
      break;
    case GEARMAN_WORK_FAIL:
      echo "Failed\n";
      exit;
    case GEARMAN_SUCCESS:
      break;
    default:
      echo "RET: " . $gmclient->returnCode() . "\n";
      exit;
  }
}
while($gmclient->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS);

?>
```

**EDIT**

It appears the segmentation fault was being caused by Imagick. So I did the following to deal with the issue.

1. Remove imagick `dpkg --purge --force-all php5-imagick`. I had installed this when I was setting up PHP
2. Restart PHP (This could vary depending on how you installed php)
3. Restart Gearman Job Server `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server stop && /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server`

Everything seems to be working ok now.

Comment: If you found the problem, post it as _an answer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is segmentation fault that means something is wrong with your installation. Run `dmesg` to see more details there may be problem with some php extension that could be disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and I get a lot of readout and at the end I get a few lines with something like this `segfault at 8 ip 00007f7e904596b0 sp 00007fff31d579f0 error 6 in libuuid.so.1.3.0[7f7e90458000+4000]`. Any idea what this could be pointing to?!

Comment: Not exactly, but now you have some real starting point. From quick google search it looks like problem with imagick, so you may try disabling this extension (if you have it installed).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like it imagick was the problem. I've edited my question with how I solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just also had this problem. 
This is the soution I took (to **fully** resolving it), and steps to observing the error.

### Step 1.

Running the Gearman Worker resulted in a:

> Segmentation fault

### Step 2.

Run `dmesg` from shell, I observed that this was showing up.

> [2423402.716386] php[21232]: segfault at 30 ip b66d0321 sp bfc704c0
>   error 6 in libuuid.so.1.3.0[b66cf000+3000]

### Step 3.

Googled for libuuid.so and it became apparent that Imagick uses `uuid_create()` for Image UUIDs.

http://usrportage.de/archives/922-PHP-segfaulting-with-pecluuid-and-peclimagick.html

### Step 4. (The solution)

I ensured that Imagick extension gets initialized last out of all of my PHP extensions. 
So previously I had in the first line of my

`/etc/php5/conf.d/extensions.ini`  file imagick.so

What I did instead was created a file called `imagick.ini` and the contents of that were

`imagick.so`

Because the extensions are loaded in alphabetical order (and if you are running your Worker through command line), loading imagick last ensures that all the dependant extensions are loaded first. In this case libuuid.